# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict

Tags: python, anaconda

I try to install

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.7
```

and get

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - prettytable -> python=3.5
  - python=3.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

There are a lot of questions with `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict` 
But I can not find with `prettytable -> python=3.5`

I have

```
3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: So what if you can't find a question for your specific package? It should be similar to the same problem with other packages.